# \newcommand that behaves like a normal word

Tags: macros

Is there any way to define a `\newcommand` that behaves like a normal word?

I have a few names for Objects, that might change later.

To keep my flexibility i use `\newcommand{\superprod}{superPRODUCT}`. If later on the name of "superPRODUCT" has to be changed to "uberPr0duct", I just have to change the new command.
But it really bothers me, that i have always have to type `\superprod\`or `\superprod{}` in my text.

Is there any way to make latex realise that a space has to be inserted after the word (except at the end of a sentence)?

Edit: No real solution, best way:

```
\newcommand{\superprod}{}% To make sure that \naive isn't already defined    
\def\superprod/{superPRODUCT}

in text:
Lorem \superprod/ ipsum \superprod/.
```

Comment: Look up `xspace` package

Comment: I'd stick with manually adding the space if required (not even one of the authors of `xspace` likes to recommend using it).